# How to route traffic from LAN to inner switch on Hyper-V?

Tags: networking, routing, hyper-v, mikrotik-routeros

I have a Hyper-V host (192.168.88.234) on my LAN network (192.168.88.0/24). Additionally the host has an Inner Switch with the address 10.0.0.1. I have added route to the Inner network through the gateway (192.168.88.1) of the LAN network (10.0.0.0/24 unicast 192.168.88.1). This case grandted access from LAN hosts to the Inner Switch vhosts, but there are not direct link between LAN hosts and Inner Switch (10.0.0.1).

I tried to add difference routes on physical host with different combinations, but not sucessfully.

What I need? I need to get access to the host 192.168.88.234 on virtual interface 10.0.0.1 from 192.168.88.251 lan host..

[There're route table from 234 host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhntM.png)

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 14... ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
  3... ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.88.1   192.168.88.234     35
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    271
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    271
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.88.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.88.234    291
   192.168.88.234  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.234    291
   192.168.88.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.234    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.88.234    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.234    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    271
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
 Метрика   Сетевой адрес            Шлюз
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

[Mikrotik routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSWV4.png)

```
Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, 
B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
 #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
 0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          pppoe-out1                1
 1 A S  10.0.0.0/24                        bridge-l                  2
 2 ADC  62.68.159.254/32   109.194.19.124  pppoe-out1                0
 3 ADC  192.168.88.0/24    192.168.88.1    bridge-l                  0
 4 ADC  192.168.99.0/24    192.168.99.1    bridge-r                  0
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The route tables should be included as text, not just as images.

Comment: Somebody told that this switch on layer 2 transparent for routing. As I understand, it is not possible to touch them by IP :\